# Complex ActiveRecord association definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

How would you map the dashed association using ActiveRecord? Is there any ActiveRecord-way of doing it? What I want is to get all unique available promotions for a particular item.

[image: Diagram]

Here are things I thought but I don't really like:

**Using custom finder**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :promotions, :finder_sql => "SELECT..FROM promotions..purchase_option_id IN (...)"
end
```

**The dirty and inefficient but rubyish way**

```
my_item.purchase_options.map(&:promotion).uniq
```

**Breaking the `PurchaseOption`<->`Promotion` HABTM association and creating a new one for `Item`<->`PromotedPurchaseOption`**

[image]

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :promoted_purchase_options
  has_many :promotions, :through => :promoted_purchase_options
end
```

**Other thoughts**

I don't think it's a good idea to use *named scopes* or defining new *methods*
This won't simply work or will execute inefficient queries if using them:

```
Item.first.promotions.count
Item.first.promotions.available
Promotion.first.items.all
```

Comment: by the way, is there a way of defining custom finders rather than writing plain SQL?

Comment: There're :select, :from options that can modify default SQL generated by AR

Comment: Why do you think using named_scopes is not a good idea? It's absolutely fine, helps a lot!

Comment: @j, because calling `Item.promotions` would return an array of `Items` instead of `Promotions`

Comment: @knoopx: In this case, I believe using a method to return `promotions` would be better than using a `named_scope`. But named_scopes are often really helpful!

Comment: @j, using a method I could not execute `Item.first.promotions.active.all(:order => "position")`

Comment: Your method can receive parameters...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchase_options
  has_many :promotions, :through => :purchase_options, :uniq => true
end
```

Comment: it would work if `PurchaseOption`<->`Promotion` association was of type `has_one`, `has_many` or `belongs_to` but not for `has_and_belongs_to`, please review the ER diagram

Comment: This is the better way to organize it. I'm with @fantactuka on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're opposed to named scopes or custom methods. These things can help reduce complexity by encapsulating a lot of the query logic. Whenever possible avoid custom finder_sql on your relationships.

If you're using a deprecated has_and_belongs_to_many relationship method, you should probably switch it to a straight join model. The has_many ..., :through approach will give you a lot more control over the links between models, and you can alter the properties of the join model directly.

Comment: I don't want named_scopes/methods because I will be chaining the association and AR won't be able to generate the proper SQL.

what do you mean by deprecated? the problem is that I don't need the "straight model", it just add complexity.

Comment: Technically it is still supported, but lacks many of the features that a has_many ... :through relationship offers, such as being able to easily update attributes on the join. Prior to there being support for :through (Rails 1.2?) these were the only way to go. I should have said "fallen out of favor" rather than strictly deprecated.

Comment: ActiveRecord is usually pretty good about figuring out what you mean when you chain associations, so it's a better way to go than rolling your own SQL unless strictly required.